# Does the Java VM provide custom stream handlers like PHP

Tags: java, php, internals

PHP's stream API provides features to create custom "streams" within the zend engine. These stream features were designed to look and feel as if they were native Unix-like file descriptors where one can fopen, fwrite, fread, fseek, etc as if a normal file, but with custom handlers that could (for example) open a database connection on fopen, perform a SQL SELECT on fread, an SQL INSERT on fwrite, etc, creating a "high-level" database API which behaves like a normal file.

These stream handlers are best when written in C/C++, and PHP/Zend provide a native API for creating stream handlers.

Does Java VM provide a native API for this type of data handling?

Comment: Do you need the streams to be real unix filesystem streams? (And what would you expect to happend, if running on Windows?).

Comment: The stream will be for a native ZeroMQ based network resource. ZeroMQ is available on many architectures and operating systems that run Java, and is pretty universal across applicable systems.

Comment: @JSON Not happy with [these](http://zeromq.org/bindings:java)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing the [`java.nio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) and *particularly* the [`java.nio.channels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html) packages. For example, the [`java.nio.channels.Channel` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channel.html) says (in part)

> A channel represents an open connection to an entity such as a hardware device, a file, a network socket, or a program component that is capable of performing one or more distinct I/O operations, for example reading or writing.